# How to round the corners of the items from recycler View

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

I am trying to set the corners of the items using **CardView** but when i swipe the item its background has the sharp corners. I am attaching image as well as code please check and tell me where i am getting wrong.

Below is the Image.

**Why it still has sharp corners ?**

[image]

1. Sharing the Android XML for that item

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
     app:cardElevation="5dp"
     android:layout_marginHorizontal="12dp"
     android:layout_marginVertical="5dp">

   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:id="@+id/CONS_STATUS"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/test_common_design"
      android:padding="1.1dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TXT_GAME_NAME"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="@font/test_nunito_semi_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Game type"
        android:textColor="@color/SECONDARY_COLOR"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout15" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TXT_GAME_STATUS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/test_nunito_semi_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Open (Running)..."
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TXT_RESULT" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TXT_RESULT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/test_nunito_semi_bold"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="987 - 65 - 432"
        android:textColor="@color/DARK_PRUSSIAN_BLUE"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TXT_GAME_NAME" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout15"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/test_item_view_top"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TXT_OPEN"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="@font/test_nunito_semi_bold"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:text="Open: 08:00 AM"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textView80"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView80"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="|"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/TXT_CLOSE"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/TXT_OPEN"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TXT_CLOSE"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="@font/test_nunito_semi_bold"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:text="Close: 08:00 PM"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView80"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout> 
   </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
   ```
2. test_common_design ( drawable )

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
      <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    </shape>
   ```